# Can 'or' logic be used in UDEV for mounting drive with unique UUIDs?

Tags: linux, udev

We do a back-up to a LaCie external rugged drive. The drive is then swapped with it's twin in the safe deposit box. While the drives have different serial numbers, for the servers purposes they are the same drive. I can't image a normal situation where both drives would ever been connected to the server at the same time, but it could be possible.

Often another drive is connected to this same server so the rugged drive doesn't always get the same dev, sometimes it gets /dev/sde1 and other times it gets assigned /dev/sdf1. I thought of solving this problem with UDEV so the UUID is always referring to the "safedepositbox" mount point, but I would want to be able to do this for either of the rugged twins.

Is there a way to set it up in UDEV that the "safedepositbox" can be assigned from either UUIDs or Serial numbers for these two drives? Again, I can't imagine a situation where both drives would be connected to the server simultaneously, but I wouldn't want to rule out that possibly.

Or is there another option to do this I'm overlooking? The way it's done now, is the drive is powered on, an fdisk -l is run to find which device it has been assigned too and then it is mounted, but this is all manual. Thanks!